# How to edit css selectors to test something in Firebug?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

How to edit selectors to test something in Firebug?

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/365060/1105167712-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/365060/1105167712-My-Desktop.png)

for example if i want to test

this

```
#Homepage #thirdCol a
```

as a

```
#Homepage #thirdCol > a
```

how to test like this in firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click an element that has the selector you want to change
2. Choose 'Inspect Element' from the menu
3. In the 'Styles' tab, look for the selector you want to change, click the link next to it
4. the style sheet will open, click the selector label and edit it. changes apply immediately

Comment: in the context menu, if you have firebug installed

Answer (score 3):

In Firebug, select the ***CSS*** tab.

The daughter bar will now show: a pause button, an "Edit" control, and the "first" CSS file, next to a down arrow.

Click on that down arrow to select the appropriate CSS file -- which you can identify in the HTML/CSS view.

Then click "Edit" and you can add, change, delete, or comment-out CSS selectors as much as needed.

ETA:  See also seanizer's answer.  Firebug's *HTML+Style* pane has direct links to the editable source of the style rules it displays.

Comment: I tried but it's not working http://shup.com/Shup/365076/11051672631-My-Desktop.png

Comment: That looks like the main CSS for SO.  It works fine for me (I can edit it).  Make sure the browser cache is on and reload the page.

Comment: yes u r right. i keep cache disable always. now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the HTML (using FireBug) and add a new style element.

```
<style type="text/css">
#Homepage #thirdCol > a {
...
}
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow changing or deleting an existing selector (unless it's coded in the html page itself).  It merely allows adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click once on the '#Homepage #thirdCol a' text that is in your screen shot
2. Choose 'Inspect in CSS Tab' from the context menu.
3. Left click once on '#Homepage #thirdCol a' (after the css tab is opened)

you should now be able to edit the selector.